# How is Icomparer.Compare() method called when Sort is implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, compare, icomparer

- **Who calls Icomparer.Compare() Method?**

Consider the following sample.

```
Array.Sort(Myfiles, new customSort())
.
.
.
private class customSort : IComparer<object>
{
 public override int Compare(obj A, obj B)
 {
   return (A.Value==B.Value?(0):((A.Value < B.Value)?(-1):(1)));
 }
}
```

If Myfiles contain collection of objects,

- **How are A and B decided**.
- **Are A and B consecutive objects in th Myfiles collection?**
- **If not, How is A and B selected from Myfiles?**
- **Does the Array.Sort() method has to do anything with it?**

Comment: Please don't edit your post if you want to ask a different question. Just create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses the introspective sort (introsort) algorithm as follows:

- If the partition size is fewer than 16 elements, it uses an insertion sort algorithm.
- If the number of partitions exceeds 2 * LogN, where N is the range of the input array, it uses a Heapsort algorithm.
- Otherwise, it uses a Quicksort algorithm.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4.aspx

For first option here is a nice gif: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#mediaviewer/File:Insertion-sort-example-300px.gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#mediaviewer/File%3aInsertion-sort-example-300px.gif)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the sort algorithm. When the algorithm has to compare two objects to determine their relative order it calls the `Compare` method.

For algorithms like Bubblesort A and B would be neighbors, for anything else I can think of right now they could be any objects in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the call occurs within the `Sort` method. All the other questions pertain to the internal implementation of the `Sort` method. Although you may peek inside the actual logic, you should not normally bother since you are only interested in the end result (i.e. your array becoming sorted).